# Rewrite subdomain as subfolder on IIS

Tags: iis, subdomain

I'm trying to use content hosted on a subdomain site as a sobfolder on same domain. (On different servers)

mydomain.com -> is main domain.
sub.mydomain.com -> is sub domain.

mydomain.com/sub -> is what I want to show my sub domain content on.

on my main domain, I changed Application Request Routing as "enable proxy" and used code below, on the web.config

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Reverse Proxy to fuarlar" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^sub/(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://sub.mydomain.com/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But It didn't work. (on www.mydomain.com/sub gives me an error  that '404 not found')

What should I make for that?
Whats wrong with my configuration?

What should my steps be?

Answer (score 0):

www.mydomain.com/sub does not match ^sub/(.*).  You are missing a slash at the end of your URL.